# Why does my image move when I give a nearby paragraph margin?

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors, margin

If I add margin to ".name" then why image moves. I've given border to all elements ("for reference"). Why is this happening?

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5vh;
    background-color: #000;
}
.percy-image{
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 60vh;
    margin-left: 50vw;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.info{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 1vh;
}
.name{
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin-top: 20vh;
    display: inline-block;
}
.role{
    font-size: 1.8vh;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fusion.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fusion</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper"> 
        <div class="info">
            <p class="name">I'M PERCY JACKSON</p>
            <p class="role">WEB DEVELOPER</p>
            <img src="man.jpg" alt="" class="percy-image">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is the Image when Margin applied!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXEyw.png)

[This is the Image when Margin no applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X7pQ.png)

Because Nothing is interrupting Image(no divs, no text, no elements).

Then Why its moving?

[Here is full code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJI8FL3J8A3H)

[Here is the Image](https://pixabay.com/photos/man-portrait-gloomy-darkness-dark-1253004/)

Comment: As a side note, you should probably not be using `inline-block` for any of this. This is a better use case for flex-box.

Comment: @disinfor they say they are a beginner, [tag:flexbox] is probably too complex for a new web dev

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur 1. Flex is not too complex. There are tons of tutorials. `grid` might be a little out of their current comfort zone. 2. Using `inline-block` isn't the best approach for this. As a beginner, it's better to learn the "correct" way rather than this approach.

Comment: Your .name element comes before your image. It's above it. So of course a margin above .name pushes .name down, and pushes down everything below it.

Since the image is below it, it gets pushed down, too.

Grid/flexbox is the answer, but requires you to learn a lot.

Comment: @disinfor no need to make a structured attack against my comment. I'm trying to make things easier for the OP, I was just saying that this may be possible without flexbox

Comment: Making things easier for the OP would include learning the correct method to approach the problem from the start. Of course OP could do this without flexbox - they could use `floats`, `tables` and try to fix their current approach using `inline-block`, however, we have much better CSS tools at our disposal now.

Comment: A side effect of using margin/padding/border on the left or right side of an element is that it may push the layout out the visible view.
You can solve the padding/border problem by adding `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` . Try to use padding instead of margin for horizontal whitespace.